# roll through list of folders in a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, collections

I am somewhat of a noob at powershell, but love it and am learning as go.  I believe this should be possible, I just don't know how.  I have googled this to death, but can't find the answer.

I have a script that grabs a list of folders based on an oracle query (oracle and powershell are working fine and that's not the problem) and places the collection of folders in a variable.  I need to #1 verify the folder exists and #2 if it does exist get the folder size.  I have tried various methods to get this, but cant get it working right, i.e. gci and measure-object etc.  The problem comes when I try to run one folder at a time.  Any advice?

Comment: Some advices: In the vast majority of the cases you're not the first one with a given task. It is actually impossible that you cannot find something useful. At least here on SO you should find something you can adapt to your particular needs. For #1 take a look at [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.2). You should read the help completely!For #2 you're on the right track - keep going! If you have a particualr piece of code you've got stuck with post it here and we're probably able to help you step further.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.